# Abigail is amazing Slang english american?

Tags: slang

okay while I read **Urban Dictionary** I saw this Slang: **Abigail** and its description is:

> Abigail
>   A Best Friend who understand everything about everyone, the most amazing person you'll ever come across, beautiful funny, talented, clever. Gets on with everyone yet chooses to have the weirdest people as best friends because deep down she is a insane crazy child! Secretly has alot of problems that she doesnt want anyone to know but ends up telling some one or another because her best friend knows her too well. She is very strong and would rather see others happy than be happy herself. Happiest when singing or acting and playing the piano. And All Round Amazing Person...

I can understand this slang could I use when a girl is cool,beautiful funny,talented,etc?

for example could I say some this way:

**my friend is funny she says some funny everyday she is abigail** this way is correct?

[Abigail - Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Abigail)

Comment: *Don't* think of Urban Dictionary as a useful resource for learning English! Most native speakers (even if they know that ***Abigail*** is in fact a girl's name) wouldn't associate it with any particular personality traits. Especially not something so "nebulous" as *cool,beautiful funny,talented,etc.*

Comment: The Urban Dictionary is not a real dictionary, but more like an archive edited by random people from the internet.  My impression is it's only about 50% accurate, as many of its definitions of slang expressions are either incorrect, or only valid in a very narrow region or dialect.  "Abigail", for example, is not a slang expression *anywhere*.  It's just a female name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yep I know abigail is a name but I saw this in Urban Dictionary and just want to know you opinion about it

Comment: If you're interested in meanings/associations of "Christian" names, perhaps you should start with your own. Per Collins dictionary, [***simony***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/simony) = *the practice, now usually regarded as a sin, of buying or selling spiritual or Church benefits such as pardons, relics, etc, or preferments.* That's real, not made-up Urban Dictionary tosh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urban dictionary is user edited.  This means that people can enter definitions for their own names, or names of friends (or enemies). There is not much editorial control on Urban dictionary.

A lot of the definitions of names are like "John: a really cool guy".  or "James: a horrid person who steals from the fridge"

In this case, all it means is that someone called "Abigail" thinks it would be funny to edit the entry for her own name.  You should not use Abigail, or any other name you find on Urban dictionary.

Comment: ok thanks I did not know that so then if I want to say this :"my friend is funny she says some funny everyday she is cool" is it correct?

Comment: I don't know your friend.  I don't know if she is cool or funny.  If she is both, then your sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: nope I want to say this expression it is just a example for make something with that slangs

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard the word "Abigail" used as a slang word for a best friend who understands everything. I have only heard it used as a person's name. I think that someone with a friend named Abigail created these entries in this "slang dictionary" as a way to please his friend.

In other words, I don't think "Abigail" is actually a slang word at all, and I would not encourage you to use the word in that way.

Comment: " as a person's name." I know

Answer (score 2):

This entry that you are quoting has quite a few errors in basic English. I have never heard this usage. Consequently, I would not rely on this entry.

Comment: I have mistake in my question? where? I acorrding to me I write well english ,basic but well

Comment: I did not say that you had made mistakes in your question (although you did). I said that what you quoted has mistakes and so is not reliable. But your English is nowhere close to being error free. For example, you confuse the words "some" and "something." You need to be taking as models people who themselves use the language carefully, not people who insert nonsense into the likes of the Urban Dictionary.

Comment: nope I know the different between some and something just that is more fast write this way but now i will going to write well in the next post so I asked this question because I am not native and I would like their opinion about it

Comment: Well, writing fast means that you appear to have a low level of skill in English. For example, "that is" should be "that it is." "Different" should be "difference." "More fast" should be "faster." And "will going to" should be "will be going to." That comes to four errors in three lines of text. I believe you when you say that you are proficient in English, but your haste gives a distinctly different impression.

Comment: with : most fast and faster they are the same , sorry I want to improve my write

Comment: "More fast" and "faster" have the same meaning, but "faster" is what is idiomatic. "I want to improve my write" is not grammatical. It should be "I want to improve my writing." If you seriously want to improve, I suggest you take a course.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded and messily punctuated. The question should begin: _While I **was reading** **the** Urban Dictionary, I saw this slang..._ And if you knew the **difference** (not the _different_) between 'some' and 'something', then you would not have asked: _could I say some this way_. Perhaps acorrding [sic] to you, you "write well english" [sic sic], but, fact is, your English is rife with basic mistakes.